Why is my CPU always at 150+ watts power usage
I just bought a new motherboard for my Alienware x17 r1 and everything seems to be working just fine but then for some reason I noticed that my CPU was being throttled. Reset the system and everything was still the same. Tried turning off the turbo boost from the BIOS, speed shift and even tried undervolting but it just doesn't change anything.
CPU-z result:

Edit: I just tried using HWinfo from sibilee's comment (sorry idk how to use this site very well) and the results are kinda funny; total system power consumed was 60-70 watts, but the processor power was still in the 150+ watts. Are my sensors fried or something?
HWinfo results:


Your CPU has a TDP of 45W - 65W. The values you see next to Power are probably erronous as even PL2 is max 109W. Try HWInfo instead of coretemp.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It looks like a sensor error (but those are inside the CPU). There's no way your CPU is pulling that kind of wattage but staying at those temps. It would hit Tmax in no time and start throttling like mad.

is there anyway to bypass this? cos my cpu keeps power throttling and it's very annoying

Well on the screenshot its showing it is /not/ throttling ? Your max temps are also pretty low (it would hit 90+ before throttling). If it is throttling anyway, you cant bypass these safety measures. I suggest contacting Alienware to help you diagnose and fix the problem.

laptops are often set by default to "throttle first, then fan" in power cfg. I forget the exact wording for the setting. Try "fan first"
